# Determining if a vector is tangent of normal to a surface.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given the parametric surface $\mathbf{r} (u, v) = (\cos{v} \sin{u}, \sin{u} \sin{v}, \cos{u})$ with $0 \leq u \leq \pi$ and $0 \leq v \leq 2 \pi,$ say which of the following statements is true:

(1) $(\cos{u} \cos{v}, \sin{u} \sin{v}, \cos{u})$ is tangent to the surface.

(2) $(\sin^{2}{u} \cos{v}, \sin^{2}{u} \sin{v}, \sin{u} \cos{u})$ is normal to the surface.

---

Now, my work:

To see if the vector in (1) is tangent to the surface I calculate the normal vector $\mathbf{N}$:

$\partial \mathbf{r}_{u} = (\cos{v} \cos{u}, \cos{u} \sin{v}, - \sin{u})$

$\partial \mathbf{r}_{u} = (- \sin{v} \sin{u}, \cos{v} \sin{u}, 0)$

$\mathbf{N} = \partial \mathbf{r}_{u} \times \partial \mathbf{r}_{v} = (\sin^{2}{u} \cos{v}, - \sin{v} \sin^{2}{u}, \sin{u} \cos{u})$

Then I see if $\mathbf{N} \cdot (\cos{u} \cos{v}, \sin{u} \sin{v}, \cos{u}) = 0.$ But this dot product equals $$\sin^{2}{u} \cos^{2}{v} \cos{u} - \sin^{3}{u} \sin^{2}{v} + \sin{u} \cos^{2}{u},$$ so this is not the case.

To see if the vector in (2) is normal to the surface I check if given vector equals $\mathbf{N}$ times a constant, but clearly it isn't.

According to one my instructor one of the statements must be true, but I am unable to determine which with my work. Is what i'm doing correct? What am I missing?

Comment: I think your cross product computation is incorrect; I get a plus sign in the second component.

Comment: @rogerl You're absolutely right. I forgot to multiply the second component by $(-1)^{1 + 2}.$ I've been making the same mistake in my whole assignment; that's why I wasn't getting anything right. Thanks.